Most of the verbs keep the suffix "e" because were used with the first-person singular in the Middle English
I’m uncertain about the ending "e" in the final form of many verbs.From the ChatGPT response: "The main factor behind the retention of the final "e" in many verbs is indeed their historical usage with the first person singular subject in Middle English. Here's a more detailed explanation:Historical Usage with First Person Singular1. Middle English Verb Conjugation:In Middle English, verbs often had distinct endings for different subjects and tenses. The first person singular form of verbs typically ended in "-e."For example, "make" in Middle English:First person singular: I make (with the pronounced final "e");Second person singular: thou makest;Third person singular: he/she/it maketh or makesPlural: we/you/they maken2. Pronounced Final "e":The final "e" in the first person singular form was pronounced. It served to indicate the subject performing the action and was part of the verb's conjugation pattern.Phonological Changes and Retention of Silent "e"1. Phonological Evolution:Over time, English underwent phonological changes, including the loss of final unstressed syllables. The pronounced final "e" in many words, including verbs, gradually became silent. Despite becoming silent, the final "e" was often retained in the spelling of verbs due to historical convention and etymological reasons.2. Retained Spelling Convention: The silent "e" in verbs like "make" persisted in spelling to maintain consistency with their historical forms and to preserve etymological connections. This silent "e" serves to indicate vowel length, distinguish homophones, and maintain historical spelling conventions.Conclusion:The retention of the final "e" in many verbs, including "make," can be attributed to their historical usage with the first person singular subject in Middle English. While the pronunciation of the final "e" changed over time, it was retained in spelling for consistency and etymological reasons. Thus, the silent "e" in verbs serves as a marker of their historical conjugation patterns and phonological evolution."Is this argument true? Does someone have a better explanation about the history of the ending "e"?

We can tell from poetic meters whether a vowel is silent or not.

Take a look at this article on spelling reform: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_spelling_reform

"-e" isn't unique to verbs. There are lots of nouns (stone, face, fate, mine, site, bane, cane, mane, nape, cape, shape, lode, pope, rope...) It's simply that "mak" and "make" would be pronounced differently. If you want an explanation of why that's the case, you have to go back even further. Many other language such as French and German have lots of words with final -e (silent in French, pronounced in German).

Looks to me like a classic example of why you should never never never ask a LLM for an explanation of why something happens. LLMs do not have knowledge: they have patterns. The graphical ones know what fingers look like, but don't "know" that there is a particular number of them in a normal hand. Text ones can come up with an explanation, and nowadays that explanation is probably not completely made-up nonsense (as it sometimes used to be); but there is no reason to suppose that the LLM can produce anything remotely resembling a thorough answer.

The retention of the 'e' suffix in verbs like your examples is connected to historical spelling conventions, but it's more complex than a straightforward rule about first-person singular forms.
In Old English, verbs had various inflexions for different tenses, moods, numbers, and persons. During the Middle English period, the language underwent significant changes. One notable change was the simplification of the inflectional system. By this time, the '-e' ending often indicated the infinitive form of verbs (similar to how we use "to" in modern English, for example, "to take"). Additionally, this '-e' could appear in some conjugated forms as a remnant of the Old English inflexions, but its use was not strictly confined to the first-person singular.
I did wonder if the origins of verbs made a difference to this (English words have roots in many languages including Latin, Old Norse French etc) but a comment by TimR was helpful in this regard - most borrow-words were absorbed into the language before the Middle English period, so the presence of the '-e' suffix was more a feature of the language's overall structure at the time rather than being specifically tied to a particular verb's origin. So, both native English verbs and those borrowed from other languages could have adopted this suffix as part of their adaptation into English.
